# Validar Formulário sem mudar de página

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu tenho uma certa `input` do `type submit` que ao clicar atua sobre uma `pagina.php`. Eu queria que fizesse isso, mas que ao clicar ela não mudasse de página, mas atuasse sobre essa tal `pagina.php`.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <form method="post" action="inserir.php">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar!">
    </form>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "vertrigo", "csgodouble");

    $contador = "0";
    while($contador < 10000){
        $contador++;
        $numero = rand(0, 14);
        $sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO apostas (numero_sorteado, hash, data_f, status) VALUES ('$numero', '0', '0', '0')");
    }
?>
```

Comment: Já tentou utilizar Ajax?

Comment: Não tenho conhecimentos de ajax.

Comment: Para conseguir fazer uma requisição para o servidor e atuar sobre a tela existente sem atualizar a página é necessário utilizar ajax.
Se você pudesse colocar um pedaço de código do formulário que você está enviando e de como seu php está recebendo isso seria mais fácil ajudar a resolver seu problema.

Comment: Editei a pergunta Vinicius.

Comment: Você utiliza jQuery ou javascript puro?

Comment: Como lhe der mais geito vinicius, para mim é indiferente.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente seu form deverá ter um id pra que possamos identificar ele com javascript

```
<html>
<form id="myform" method="post" action="inserir.php">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar!">
  </form>
  </html>
```

Após isso temos que adicionar o script para baixar a biblioteca jQuery no seu site.

Adicione a seguinte tag em seu header

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

Agora você terá que fazer um javascript para enviar a requisição para o seu servidor utilizando Ajax quando clicar no botão submit.

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e) {
    var url = "inserir.php"; 
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#myform").serialize(),
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data);
               //utilizar o dado retornado para alterar algum dado da tela.
           }
         });

    e.preventDefault();// esse comando serve para previnir que o form realmente realize o submit e atualize a tela.
});
```